# 'Can't convert Symbol into Integer' - issue with Simple_Form and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, typeerror

I'm getting the following error:

TypeError in Devise/registrations#new
Action Controller: Exception Caught - can't convert Symbol into Integer

I started getting this error when I added the **'ed f.association line below.

This is puzzling to me because I've followed both the Rails guides association documentation, as well as the simple_form documentation:

#### Simple_Form Example

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.association :company %>
  <%= f.association :roles %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

#### My Simple_Form Execution

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
  **<%= f.association :competition %>**

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

#### These are the models in question:

```
class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :rounds, :judges
end

class Judge < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name
  belongs_to :competition
end
```

#### I've done the following migration:

```
class AddAssocToJudges < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :judges do |t|
      t.belongs_to :competition
    end
  end
end
```

#### Here's the application trace:

```
app/models/competition.rb:4:in `<class:Competition>'
app/models/competition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__3768524909032037243_70228371062560'
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__3768524909032037243_70228371062560'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but `rounds` and `judges` are 2 different tables, right?

And they both are associated to `competitions` without scoping, correct?

If it's the case, you should have 2 distinct lines for your `has_many` associations in your `Competition` class, like thie:

```
class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :rounds
  has_many :judges
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define `has_many` in different lines:

```
has_many :rounds
has_many :judges
```